# coefficients of the zeta function of curve over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, zeta-functions

Let $C$ be a non-singular curve over $\mathbb{F}_q$. 
Denote by $d$ the degree map from the group of divisors to $\mathbb{Z}$ 
and denote by $P$ the set of prime divisors w.r.t. to the function field.

> Let $C_n$ be the curve obtained from $C$ by extending $\mathbb{F}_q$ to $\mathbb{F}_q^n$. 
>   Is there a bijection between $\{P \text{ prime divisor of } C_n: d(P)=1\}$ and  $\{P \text{ prime divisor of } C: d(P)|n\}$

Following is the context (see also [C. Moreno, curves over finite fields](http://books.google.ch/books?id=L8YnlDqV3MoC&printsec=frontcover&hl=de&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false/%22C.%20Moreno,%20Curves%20over%20finite%20fields%22%22)):

Let $C$ be a non-singular curve over $\mathbb{F}_q$. 
Denote by $d$ the degree map from the group of divisors to $\mathbb{Z}$ 
and denote by $P$ the set of prime divisors w.r.t. to the function field.

The zeta function of $C$ is defined by $Z(t,C):= \sum_{D} {t^{d(D)}} $, where the sum goes through all positive divisors.

One can show that

Theorem: $Z(t,C)=exp(\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}N_m \frac{t^m}{m})$, where $N_m:=\sum_{P,d(P)|m}{d(P)}$ and $N_1$ is equal the number of prime divisors of degree $1$.

Theorem: $N_n=N_1(C_n)$, where $N_1(C_n)$ denotes corresponding $N_1$ w.r.t. to $Z(t,C_n)$ and $N_n$ w.r.t. $Z(t,C)$ as defined above.

Now obviously, we have that $N_1(C_n)$ is equal to the number of prime divisors $P$ of $C_n$ with $d(P)=1$. But now it's immediately deduced that this is equal to number of prime divisors of $C$ with $d(P)|n$, but I don't unterstand this deduction. How this works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's better to write the zeta function using points, i.e.

$$Z(t, C) = \exp\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \#\overline{C}(\mathbb F_{q^n}) \frac{t^n}{n}\right),$$

where $\overline{C}$ denotes the base change of $C$ to $\overline{\mathbb F_q}$.

A prime divisor $P$ on $C_n$ of degree $1$ is precisely the same thing as an $\mathbb F_{q^n}$-rational point of $C_n$.  The points in $C_n(\mathbb F_{q^n})$ have an action of $\text{Gal}(\mathbb F_{q^n}/\mathbb F_q)$, a cyclic group of order $n$; the orbits of this action correspond to closed points of $C/\mathbb F_q$ whose residue field is contained in $\mathbb F_{q^n}$. Such a point is precisely a prime divisor on $C$ whose degree divides $n$, since the finite field $\mathbb F_q$ has a unique extension of degree $d$ for every $d$.

Comment: I must admit my knowledge about algebraic geometriy is rather weak. 

By $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}$-rational point of $C_n$ is meant a point, whose coordinates are elements of $\mathbb{F}_{q^n}$?

How this correspondence between those special closed points of $C/\mathbb{F}_q$ the orbits by $Gal(\mathbb{F}_q^n /\mathbb{F}_q)$ look like exactly?

How does a residue field of a point$(x_1, x_2)$ look like?
Maybe so $\mathbb{F}_q)[X,Y]/(X -x_1, Y-x_2)$?

Comment: Thanks now it's clear (after some additional literature).